# Conflict JavaScript templating

Tags: node.js, swig-template, dot.js

I am writing project on [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) + [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) with templating [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/).
On the user side using a template system [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html)

The question arose in the browser to pass a line like:

```
<h1> string {{= it.stringVar}} </ h1>
```

But I do not know how to make Swig not handle as part of the string variable (ie not handle braces).

Is there any mechanism to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% raw %}<h1> string {{= it.stringVar}} </ h1>{% endraw %}
```

Read more in [swig docs](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#raw).